# Different CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and SYSDATE in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle10g

After executing this SQL in oracle 10g:

```
SELECT SYSDATE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  FROM DUAL
```

I receive this strange output:
[image: Toad output for query]

What is cause of the difference in time? 
The server time is equal of SYSDATE value

Answer (score 128, accepted):

[`CURRENT_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions044.htm) and [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions045.htm) return the current date and time in the session time zone.

[`SYSDATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions191.htm) and [`SYSTIMESTAMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions192.htm) return the system date and time - that is, of the system on which the database resides.

If your client session isn't in the same timezone as the server the database is on (or says it isn't anyway, via your NLS settings), mixing the `SYS*` and `CURRENT_*` functions will return different values. They are all correct, they just represent different things. It looks like your server is (or thinks it is) in a +4:00 timezone, while your client session is in a +4:30 timezone.

You might also see small differences in the time if the clocks aren't synchronised, which doesn't seem to be an issue here.

Answer (score 29):

`SYSDATE`, `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns the Database's date and timestamp, whereas `current_date`, `current_timestamp` returns the date and timestamp of the location from where you work.

For eg. working from India, I access a database located in Paris. at 4:00PM IST:

`select sysdate,systimestamp from dual;` 
  
  This returns me the date and Time of Paris:

> RESULT

```
12-MAY-14   12-MAY-14 12.30.03.283502000 PM +02:00
```

`select current_date,current_timestamp from dual;` 
 
  This returns me the date and Time of India:

> RESULT

```
12-MAY-14   12-MAY-14 04.00.03.283520000 PM ASIA/CALCUTTA
```

*Please note the 3:30 time difference.*

Comment: I am using CURRENT_TIMESTAMP for Insert. Application and Database are running in Singapore & Client browser in India.. When inserting via application[Browser] its inserts Malaysia time only

Answer (score 5):

SYSDATE returns the system date, of the system on which the database resides

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the current date and time in the session time zone, in a value of datatype TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

execute this comman

```
    ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE = '+3:0';
```

and it will provide you the same result.

Comment: +4:30 means Iran Summer Time . There is Iran and now is summer! Why shold I change my time zone?!

Comment: becasue SYSDATE returns the system date, of the system on which the database resides. The return type is TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns the current date and time in the session time zone, in a value of datatype TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE

Answer (score 2):

- `SYSDATE` provides date and time of a server.
- `CURRENT_DATE` provides date and time of client.(i.e., your system)
- `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` provides data and timestamp of a clinet.

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** `SYSDATE` - returns only the date, i.e., "yyyy-mm-dd" is not correct. `SYSDATE` returns the system date of the database server including hours, minutes, and seconds. For example:

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

will return output similar to the following: 12/15/2017 12:42:39 PM

Answer (score -5):

1. `SYSDATE`, `systimestamp` return datetime of server where database is installed. `SYSDATE` - returns only date, i.e., "yyyy-mm-dd". `systimestamp` returns date with time and zone, i.e., "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:ms timezone"
2. `now()` returns datetime at the time statement execution, i.e., "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
3. `CURRENT_DATE` - "yyyy-mm-dd", `CURRENT_TIME` - "hh:mm:ss", `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` - "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss timezone". These are related to a record insertion time.