# Oracle sql timezone issue

Tags: sql, oracle, casting, timezone, sysdate

My requirement here is to get time in GMT/UTC from a date type column. But when I use cast to cast date to timestamp, it is using US/Pacific timezone as reference though session timezone is set to GMT. So unless I use from_tz, I am not seeing desired result. Is there any other timezone setting in oracle sql that I need to modify to take GMT as reference always?

```
alter session set time_zone='+00:00';
select sessiontimezone from dual;
select current_timestamp from dual;
select sys_extract_utc(cast (sysdate as timestamp)) from dual;
select sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast (sysdate as timestamp), '-07:00')) from dual;
select sys_extract_utc(current_timestamp) from dual;


Session altered.


SESSIONTIMEZONE
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
+00:00


CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-APR-16 08.46.42.292173 AM +00:00


SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-APR-16 01.46.42.000000 AM

SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATEASTIMESTAMP),'-07:00'))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-APR-16 08.46.42.000000 AM


SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
11-APR-16 08.46.42.295310 AM
```

Tasks table has a date type column called task_started. I am looking to get UTC time from this date field. As part of that I was trying to alter session timezone to GMT while inserting the data so that I can simply cast it back to timestamp which is not working.

```
select task_started from tasks where rownum <2;

TASK_STAR
---------
10-APR-16

desc tasks;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
...
 TASK_STARTED                                       DATE
...
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a stored date (with time) and the output you expect? What time zone does the date/time in that column represent, and how do you know - is there another column storing its time zone, or are you assuming some conversion is needed?

Comment: @AlexPoole My table has only date stored, so I am casting this back to timestamp. I assume date/time stored in the table should be using session timezone which is GMT as I have altered session time zone. Since cast function is returning back time in US/Pacific I got confused.

Comment: A date column has no time zone (but does always have a time, even if your query/client isn't showing that). If you cast as a plain timestamp the time will stay the same but it will still have no time zone info. Your question is about converting the date/time to UTC, which implies it's stored or provided from a specific zone. E.g. if the date was originally inserted using sysdate, which implies the server time zone, and you want the UTC equivalent of that. Please add data and output as it's no clear what you really need.

Comment: But what are you actually trying to do, just see the time? `select to_char(task_started, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from tasks ...` will show that as a string. If you're comparing the date with other then the time is used for that comparison anyway. (Only convert to a string for display).

Comment: Updated the question with more info. As part of epoch number generation which always uses GMT as reference, I wanted to get GMT time from the date column first and then generate epoch from the time. As you mentioned, looks like server timezone is US/Pacific and its being used while I convert date to time.

Comment: So the date/time stored in `task_started` is US/Pacific, having been inserted using `sysdate`? And you want the UTC epoch time from that?

Comment: Yes, date/time is inserted using sysdate and dbtimezone says '-08:00'.
And I wanted to generate epoch from this date column.

Comment: @YaswanthGelli Note, value of `SYSDATE` is **not** based on `DBTIMEZONE`. Time zone of `SYSDATE` and `SYSTIMESTAMP` are based on the time zone of the database operating system.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a demo using data inserted using `sysdate` on a system on London time, so currently on BST (+01:00). The difference is smaller than you'd see on the west coast but the same things apply.

Mimicking your table, you can see that the session time zone has no effect on the inserted value since `sysdate` uses the database server time, not the session (client) time ([as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925834/266304)):

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
alter session set nls_timestamp_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3';
alter session set nls_timestamp_tz_format = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF3 TZH:TZM';

create table tasks (id number, task_started date);

alter session set time_zone='America/Los_Angeles';

insert into tasks (id, task_started) values (1, sysdate);

select task_started, cast(task_started as timestamp) as ts
from tasks where rownum < 2;

TASK_STARTED        TS                    
------------------- -----------------------
2016-04-11 11:55:59 2016-04-11 11:55:59.000

alter session set time_zone = 'UTC';

select task_started, cast(task_started as timestamp) as ts
from tasks where rownum < 2;

TASK_STARTED        TS                    
------------------- -----------------------
2016-04-11 11:55:59 2016-04-11 11:55:59.000
```

So that's the BST time in both cases. There isn't any session or database setting that will show you a date (or timestamp, without a time zone)  converted to a specific time zone automatically. The database doesn't know what that stored date/time represents unless you tell it. It doesn't know or case if you use `sysdate`, `current_date`, or a date literal; at the point the data is inserted into the table it has no time zone information at all.

To get the UTC equivalent you need to use `from_tz` to declare that the stored value represents a specific time zone; then you can use `at time zone` (which keeps the time zone info) or `sys_extract_utc` (which doesn't) on that to convert it; and optionally cast back to a date:

```
select from_tz(cast(task_started as timestamp), 'Europe/London') as db_tstz,
  from_tz(cast(task_started as timestamp), 'Europe/London') at time zone 'UTC' as utc_tstz,
  sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(task_started as timestamp), 'Europe/London')) as utc_ts,
  cast(sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(task_started as timestamp), 'Europe/London')) as date) as utc_date
from tasks where rownum < 2;

DB_TSTZ                        UTC_TSTZ                       UTC_TS                  UTC_DATE          
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ----------------------- -------------------
2016-04-11 11:55:59.000 +01:00 2016-04-11 10:55:59.000 +00:00 2016-04-11 10:55:59.000 2016-04-11 10:55:59
```

I've used the time zone region name so it takes care of summer time for me; you could use `dbtimezone` but that would always use -08:00, and as you showed in the question you need to use -07:00 at the moment. ANd you could use `sessiontimezone` but then you have to remember to set that properly. Obviously in your case you'd use your local region, e.g. America/Los_Angeles, instead of Europe/London.

And from that you can get the epoch, via an interval by comparing timestamps or more simply from comparing dates:

```
select sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(task_started as timestamp), 'Europe/London'))
    - timestamp '1970-01-01 00:00:00' as diff_interval,
  cast(sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(task_started as timestamp), 'Europe/London')) as date)
    - date '1970-01-01' as diff_days,
  86400 *
    (cast(sys_extract_utc(from_tz(cast(task_started as timestamp), 'Europe/London')) as date)
      - date '1970-01-01') as epoch
from tasks where rownum < 2;

DIFF_INTERVAL    DIFF_DAYS       EPOCH
---------------- --------- -----------
16902 10:55:59.0  16902.46  1460372159
```

If you put 1460372159 into an online converter (there are many) it will show the UTC time.