# Escaping two single quotes in JDBC PreparedStatement parameter

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

I am trying to insert values into Oracle 10g database table. I want to insert value for column **FirstName** and value is having two single quotes like this: 
**O'Rielly's Edition**.

I am using the prepared statement of JDBC to pass the value for parameter **FirstName**. It is working fine with one single quote(O'Rielly).

But when I use two single quotes it's giving SQL error as `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`. Any suggestions on how to handle two single quotes in PreparedStatement?
My query is as below:

```
StringBuffer strUpdateUserQuery = new StringBuffer("UPDATE USERS set FNAME = ? , LNAME = ?, USER_TIMEZONE = ?, CREATED_DATE = CURRENT_DATE, ACTIVE_STATUS = ?, APPROVAL_STATUS = ?,USER_GROUP_ID = ? where USER_ID = ?");

pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(strUpdateUserQuery.toString());
pstmt.setString(1, userVO.getFirstName());
pstmt.setString(2, userVO.getLastName());
pstmt.setString(3, userVO.getStrTimeZone());
pstmt.setString(4, userVO.getStatus());
pstmt.setString(5, userVO.getStrAppStatus());
pstmt.setInt(6, Integer.parseInt(userVO.getUserGroupId()));
pstmt.setString(7, userVO.getUserId());

int iCount = pstmt.executeUpdate(strUpdateUserQuery.toString());
```

And the error I am getting is as below:

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis\n

With above code, I am getting the issue.

Comment: Show an example of what you are trying to insert using preparedStatement.

Comment: You don't need to escape single quotes in bind values. Please edit your question to show the actual prepared statement you are using. (And the value, I suppose, exactly as it's bound). What is the full error you get back?

Comment: One of the important advantages of a PreparedStatement is the fact that you don't need to worry about escaping. It sounds as if you are not using the PreparedStatement correctly. **[edit]** your question and add the code you are using. Do **not** post code in comments.

Comment: And what is the string you are passing to FirstName?

Comment: I am trying to insert O''keffe as FName value.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani What exactly is `CREATED_DATE = CURRENT_DATE`, you mean `SYSDATE`?

Comment: Yes, it's similar to SYSDATE but takes current date value from the User's session.

Comment: @user75ponic - https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925834/266304 *8-)

Comment: @BabannaDuggani Try printing the output of each of the parameter, perhaps the any one would have a parenthesis which is causing an `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis`

Comment: What you've shown should get ORA-01008: not all variables bound; don't pass the query string in again (as gprathour said). You'll get the same error(s) with one or two single quotes though.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani Any why would you need `StringBuffer`? Rather a `String` is enough for this in my opinion.

Comment: I don't see a reason for this error. Are you really sure it is coming from here?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

```
int iCount = pstmt.executeUpdate(strUpdateUserQuery.toString());
```

to

```
int iCount = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```