# Time subtraction format result

Tags: oracle, time, format

I'm having trouble formatting the result of my time calculation as well as searching for a forum solution. I do not wish to view the "hours from UTC" leading the result (the +09).

```
select
(localtimestamp - to_timestamp(us.STARTDATETIME,'hh24:mi:ss')) as HoursPassed
from random us
```

Where `us.STARTDATETIME` is a `varchar2` with something like `08:00`

My result:

> +09 07:30:17.160826

Desired result:

> 07:30:17

Comment: The +09 is days from the first of the month, not hours from UTC. Is there a reason you're using timestamps, and session time zone rather than system time zone? Does the `startdatetime` represent a specific time zone?

Comment: @Alex Poole No there is no requirement to use a session timezone. startdatetime does not represent a specific time zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you [subtract one timestamp from another](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#g196492) the result is an internal interval data type, but you can treat it as ['interval day to second'](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00207):

```
select
(localtimestamp - to_timestamp(us.STARTDATETIME,'hh24:mi:ss')) as HoursPassed
from random us;

HOURSPASSED        
-------------------
+08 15:26:54.293892
```

The '+08' (in my session time zone) is the number of days, not a UTC offset; that is the value it is because when you convert a string to a date or timestamp and only provide the time part, the date part [defaults to the first day of the current month](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50988):

> The default date values are determined as follows:
>
> - The year is the current year, as returned by SYSDATE.
> - The month is the current month, as returned by SYSDATE.
> - The day is 01 (the first day of the month).
> - The hour, minute, and second are all 0.
>
> These default values are used in a query that requests date values where the date itself is not specified ...

So I'm really comparing:

```
select localtimestamp, to_timestamp(us.STARTDATETIME,'hh24:mi:ss')
from random us;

LOCALTIMESTAMP             TO_TIMESTAMP(US.STARTDATET
-------------------------- --------------------------
2017-08-09 23:26:54.293892 2017-08-01 08:00:00.000000
```

You can't directly format an interval, but you can [extract](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions067.htm) the elements of the time and format those separately, and concatenate them.

```
select to_char(extract(hour from (localtimestamp
    - to_timestamp(us.STARTDATETIME, 'hh24:mi:ss'))), 'FM00')
  ||':'|| to_char(extract(minute from (localtimestamp
    - to_timestamp(us.STARTDATETIME, 'hh24:mi:ss'))), 'FM00')
  ||':'|| to_char(extract(second from (localtimestamp
    - to_timestamp(us.STARTDATETIME, 'hh24:mi:ss'))), 'FM00')
  as hourspassed
from random us;

HOURSPASSED
-----------
15:26:54
```

Repeatedly calculating the same interval looks a bit wasteful and hard to manage, so you can do that in an inline view or a CTE:

```
with cte (diff) as (
  select localtimestamp - to_timestamp(us.STARTDATETIME, 'hh24:mi:ss')
  from random us
)
select to_char(extract(hour from diff), 'FM00')
  ||':'|| to_char(extract(minute from diff), 'FM00')
  ||':'|| to_char(extract(second from diff), 'FM00')
  as hourspassed
from cte;

HOURSPASSED
-----------
15:26:54
```

You could also use dates instead of timestamps; subtraction then gives you the difference as a number, with whole and fractional days:

```
select current_date - to_date(us.STARTDATETIME, 'hh24:mi') as hourspassed
from random us;

HOURSPASSED
-----------
 8.64368056
```

The simplest way to format that is to add it to a known midnight time and then use `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01'
  + (current_date - to_date(us.STARTDATETIME, 'hh24:mi')),
  'HH24:MI:SS') as hourspassed
from random us;

HOURSPAS
--------
15:26:54
```

I've stuck with `current_date` as the closest match to `localtimestamp`; you may actually want `systimestamp` and/or `sysdate`. (More on the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925834/266304).)