# Converting INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get more readable value using interval data type.

```
select cast(last_run_duration as INTERVAL DAY TO SECOND(0))
from dba_scheduler_jobs
order by 1 desc;
```

Query result like this;

```
+00 00:00:04.630530
+00 00:00:01.352359
+00 00:00:00.737282
+00 00:00:00.594381
+00 00:00:00.432710
```

What i want is this. Only getting Hour:minute:second ;

```
 00:00:04
 00:00:01
 00:00:00
 00:00:00
 00:00:00
```

last_run_duration column's datatype is  `INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND(6)`

Comment: Not an exact duplicate maybe, but [the second half of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601629/266304) shows some options.

Comment: Looks like you want `hour to second(0)`.

Comment: @jarlh `cast(last_run_duration as interval hour to second(0)` gives me _ORA-00963: unsupported interval type_ in 12.1.0.2.0.

Comment: Your query gives me values like `+00 01:26:24` in SQL*Plus (Oracle 12.1.0.2.0, client 11.2.0.2.0). Casting to `INTERVAL DAY(0) TO SECOND(0))` loses one of the leading zeroes. To strip those you can use `substr` if you know it will never be more than a day. If you want something like `36:12:34` that's going to be trickier. Is that possible in your situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`INTERAVL DAY TO SECOND` has a fixed output format, `TO_CHAR` does not work.

Either use `EXTRACT` as proposed by Edumelzer

```
select lpad(extract(hour from last_run_duration),2,'0')||':'||
       lpad(extract(minute from last_run_duration),2,'0')||':'||
       lpad(round(extract(second from last_run_duration)),2,'0') as duration
  from dba_scheduler_jobs
 order by 1 desc;
```

or use substring like

```
select 
REGEXP_SUBSTR(last_run_duration, '\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
from from dba_scheduler_jobs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using [extract](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions050.htm):

```
select lpad(extract(hour from last_run_duration),2,'0')||':'||
       lpad(extract(minute from last_run_duration),2,'0')||':'||
       lpad(round(extract(second from last_run_duration)),2,'0') as duration
  from dba_scheduler_jobs
 order by 1 desc;
```

Comment: In case the `day` component could ever be > 0, you might also extract `day`, multiply by 24 and add to `hour`, to give 1.5 days as `36:00:00`.