# NUMTODSINTERVAL function changes from Oracle 10g to Oracle 12c

Tags: sql, oracle, date

Our Oracle database upgraded from 10g to 12c recently which resulted in a lot of changes to reporting.  The below logic used to return data in a `16:25:10` format:

```
to_char( numtodsinterval(
 (select max(date_entered)
  from co_hist
                where order_no = a.order_no
                and   message_text = 'Delivered')
 -
 (select max(date_entered)
  from co_hist
                where order_no = a.order_no
                and   instr(message_text,'Picklist') != 0
                and   instr(message_text,'picked') != 0), 'DAY') ) elapsed_picked_delivered
```

After the upgrade, the data returned from the same exact section of logic is: `+000000000 16:25:10.000000000`

I'm only still needing the `16:25:10`.  Is there an easier way than using the `substr()` function to strip the leading/trailing 0s?

Comment: you can mention the time format as well. like `TO_CHAR(<your_query>, 'HH:MI:SS');`

Comment: @AnkitBajpai - that doesn't work for intervals - it's just ignored, isn't it?

Comment: I don't recall it looking any different in 10g, but anyway, there are a few ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45601629/266304) on how to get the format you want, as a string. You can also do `cast(numtodsinterval(...) as interval day(0) to second(0)` but that still gives you a single digit for the number of days - which could be useful of course; and you could substr that off if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm only still needing the 16:25:10. Is there an easier way than using
> the substr() function to strip the leading/trailing 0s?

one of the solutions:

```
regexp_substr(to_char(numtodsinterval (...your code...,'DAY')),'\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}')
```

N.B.
doesn't work for interval types

```
TO_CHAR(<your_query>, 'HH:MI:SS')
```

Comment: >>if you want to make "seconds" optional

no,it's typo...