# Select data between timestamps

Tags: sql, oracle

Usecase: Query to select the records for a whole day and it should run regularly.

This is my query.

```
Select to_char(in_date + interval '12' hour, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') 
from my_table 
where incoming_date > sysdate-2 and incoming_date < sysdate
```

I need to select yesterday's data only. Because of the conversion in the select statement I got today's data also. How do I select only yesterday's data? My DB is in UTC+7.00 standard. I need to display it in local standard so that I did a conversion in select statement. And how do I display only yesterday's data? 
I'm stuck. Please help me

Comment: Can you include some sample data?

Answer (score 2):

To get all data from yesterday you should use

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(IN_DATE + INTERVAL '12' HOUR, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  FROM MY_TABLE
  WHERE INCOMING_DATE BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
                          AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND
```

If, for example, SYSDATE is 05-NOV-2017 18:56:35, the time interval used in the BETWEEN comparison will be from 04-NOV-2017 00:00:00 to 04-NOV-2017 23:59:59. BETWEEN comparisons are inclusive of both endpoints so this will only return data with an INCOMING_DATE of sometime on 04-NOV-2017, in this example.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

only to get the

> yesterday's data

make your
 *`WHERE`* condition as

```
incoming_date between trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' day and trunc(sysdate) - interval '1' second
```

Answer (score 1):

> My DB is in UTC+7.00 standard. I need to display it in local standard so that I did a conversion in select statement.

Using a magic value (`INTERVAL '12' HOUR`) does not describe what it means or the assumptions you made when chosing that value. Instead you can better describe the process by using `FROM_TS( timestampvalue, timezonestring )` to convert the value from a `TIMESTAMP` to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type and then use `AT LOCAL TIME` to convert it to the local time. Then if you have daylight savings time or port the query to another international location then it will still display in the current local time. Like this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ( CAST( in_date AS TIMESTAMP ), '+07:00' ) AT LOCAL TIME,
         'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
       ) 
FROM   my_table 
WHERE  incoming_date >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY
AND    incoming_date <  TRUNC( SYSDATE )
```

> And how do I display only yesterday's data?

`TRUNC( SYSDATE )` will truncate today's date back to midnight. To get yesterday's data then you can get values that are greater or equal to `TRUNC( SYSDATE ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY` (one day before midnight today) and also less than  `TRUNC( SYSDATE )` (midnight today).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure I get your question, but I think I can explain some stuff.

I'll be assuming your table is a bit like this:

```
 date_added | some_data | some_more_data 
------------|-----------|----------------
 date       | data1     | data2
```

As I understand your goal is to fetch all the rows that were added to a table the day before the query is run using a select statement. but your current attempt fails at doing so by also returning today's results.

Here is what's happening (I think):
`SYSDATE` doesn't just give you the current date, it also gives you the time. You can see that for your self by simply altering your current session and setting the date/time format to one that includes both time and date

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

The reason why you would be getting today's rows is simple, your query is asking for all the rows who's date_added field is between `right now` and `right now - 24 hours`. Not `today` and `today - 24 hours`.

So what is the solution?
Use the `TRUNC` function to trim the `SYSDATE` to the day instead!
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm

```
SELECT
    T.*
FROM
    MY_TABLE T
WHERE
    T.DATE_ADDED BETWEEN (TRUNC(SYSDATE,'day') - 1) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE,'day');
```

As you did mention timezones being a thing keep in mind that `SYSDATE` returns the date on the server itself and not your computer's.
More on that here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925834/7655979

Answer (score 0):

Usually I compare the date only using Trunc.

```
WHERE trunc(incoming_date) = trunc(sysdate-1)
```