# Can not get the last 5 minute inserted rows through "current_timetsamp" or "systimestamp"

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

Im trying to execute

`select * from WMERROR where INSERTTIMESTAMP > SYSTIMESTAMP - (5/(24*60))`.

Oracle 12C DB is in CEST Timezone.so i tried SQL statement on both client side(INDIA) and on machine located at CEST timezone??
Why SQL is Not yeildng results ,which is executed without errors.??

help me to resolve this usecase.
Thanks

Comment: Are there any records with a timestamp > 5 minutes ago?

Comment: @Rene yes timestamp field named " INSERTTIMESTAMP "

Comment: What is the max(inserttimestamp) ?

Comment: i got this 2018-03-29 07:25:41.037917 for max(inserttimestamp),

Comment: Also check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922106/different-current-timestamp-and-sysdate-in-oracle

Comment: select * from WMERROR where INSERTTIMESTAMP > SYSTIMESTAMP - (5/(24*60)) -tried this on machine which resides in same timezone of db,still not working??what might be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 5/(24*60)` will convert the timestamp to a date to perform the subtraction of the fractions of days so is effectively:

```
CAST( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS DATE ) - 5/(24*60)
```

This removes the time zone information and may cause your issues as

```
CASE
WHEN TIMESTAMP '2019-03-29 12:00:00+08:00'
     >= CAST( TIMESTAMP '2019-03-29 12:00:00+08:00' AS DATE )
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Outputs `0`.

Instead, you can use an `INTERVAL` literal:

```
select *
from   wmerror
where  INSERTTIMESTAMP >= current_timestamp  - INTERVAL '5' MINUTE;
```

Comment: still im not getting expected output, sql is executed without any errors.

Comment: @NaveenaKN Please edit your question with a [MCVE] including DDL statements for your table, DML statements for sample data that replicates the problem and your expected results. Without this we are guessing (and you may find that producing a [MCVE] helps you to work out a solution to your own problem).