# Why do oracle triggers show a different timestamp what is being inserted

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

My table has a Trigger that stores current_timestamp into a field when the row in the table is updated.

When a row is first inserted it is inserted with a Created date equal to `Current_Timestamp`. It appears when the procedure inserts the created_date it is given the correct time for daylight savings time but the trigger is inserting the incorrect time.

So the records in question are showing a created date of `'2018-03-11 03:13:53.392086000'` and a modified date of `'2018-03-11 02:13:53.392086000'`.

To add to this, we use goldengate for replication and it is using `'2018-03-11 03:13:53.392086000'` as the audit timestamp and not `'2018-03-11 02:13:53.392086000'`

Why would a trigger show a time differently then goldengate and the insert? database version I am working with is Oracle 11.2.0.4.0.

Trigger that handles the insert modified time

```
create or replace trigger UT_INSERT before insert on MYTABLE
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW OLD AS OLDROW FOR EACH ROW
 begin
    :NEWROW.MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
 end;
```

Trigger for updated modified time

```
create or replace trigger UT_UPDATE before update on MYTABLE
 REFERENCING NEW AS NEWROW OLD AS OLDROW FOR EACH ROW
 begin
    :NEWROW.MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP := CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
 end;
```

Comment: **[edit]** your question and include the code of the trigger

Comment: What is the data type of column `MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: TIMESTAMP(6) is the datatype for all timestamps in my table

Comment: What is setting `created_date` - is that using `systimestamp` or `current_timestamp`? (I assume you know [the difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925834/266304).) Are all the sessions doing insert/update inthe sametime zone? Are the columns plain timestamps, or with [local] time zone?

Comment: The insert statement that is setting created_date is using Current_timestamp. All sessions are currently using a TZ offset of -05:00 and the sessiontimezone is America/Chicago. I did notice that DBTIMEZONE is set to a offset of 0:00. At first i thought it could be the issue causing weird values from the trigger but if I try `select current_timestamp, systimestamp from dual;`  returns **2018-07-09 04.26.44.631014000 PM AMERICA/CHICAGO 2018-07-09 04.26.44.631009000 PM -05:00**. All Timestamps are timestamp(6) without timezone

Comment: Where does the insert procedure live? Is it a stored procedure in the db or some client side code in Forms or SQL script? Try using `systimestamp` in all instances as pointed out by @AlexPoole

Answer (score 2):

> The insert statement that is setting created_date is using Current_timestamp. All sessions are currently using a TZ offset of -05:00 and the sessiontimezone is America/Chicago.

That can't always be true. The only way to get the two values you have is for the insert to have been done with `created_date` set to `systimestamp` and for the session that issued that to have had it's session time zone set to -05:00, *not* to America/Chicago.

The reason that must be the case is that there was no 02:13 on March 11th because of the DST change:

```
select timestamp '2018-03-11 03:13:53.392086000 America/Chicago' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2018-03-1103:13:53.392086000AMERICA
---------------------------------------------
2018-03-11 03:13:53.392086000 AMERICA/CHICAGO

select timestamp '2018-03-11 02:13:53.392086000 America/Chicago' from dual;

Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01878: specified field not found in datetime or interval
01878. 00000 -  "specified field not found in datetime or interval"

select timestamp '2018-03-11 02:13:53.392086000 -5:00' from dual;

TIMESTAMP'2018-03-1102:13:53.3920860
------------------------------------
2018-03-11 02:13:53.392086000 -05:00
```

So assuming the column value was set from your trigger, which seems entirely reasonable, the session which did that must have been -05:00 to be able to have got the timestamp at 02:13; and the `created_date` must have been using `systimestamp`, where the server OS had the correct time zone of America/Chicago to pick up the DST change (ignore `dbtimezone` for this), to have got 03:13 at the same moment in time.

As long as the session time zone and server time zone are the same you won't see a discrepancy between using `current_timestamp` or `systimestamp`, but you can't always control how sessions are configured, so a mistake or deliberate time zone change can cause problems like this.

Unless you are specifically trying to record a user's local time for some reason (and then you should probably be using a timestamp data type that preserves the time zone), it's safer to always use `systimestamp` for all of the values you record; and if you're storing as a plain timestamp then it might be safer to always store UTC time.

(Changing to UTC now, particularly with existing data to worry about, probably isn't an option; and not sure how Golden Gate would handle that but seems like a common scenario. Something to think about for the future though. Changing to always use `systimestamp` ought to be fairly transparent, except that you have this and probably other discrepancies to worry about. Finding and changing all code that might do inserts could be an issue - but then you seem to have inconsistencies already).

Comment: What session parameters does a trigger use when it fires? Is it the user that created the trigger or  the user that did the insert/update on the table to fire the trigger?

Comment: @user3753693 - the user that did the insert/update. Which is why you, as the trigger creator, have no control over how it will be called later - so should use things you can control like `systimestamp` and not things you can't like `current_timestamp`, or any NLS settings like date formats etc.