# how to use Current Timestamp in SQL query (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to run the query to show the data before 30 days and after 30 days, I know i should use CURRENT TIMESTAMP to do this and I'm able to run data before 30 days but not after 30 days. Below is my query and kindly advise this situation. Thanks!

```
COB.COB_FA  > CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 30 days and COB.COB_FA  > CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 30 days
```

Comment: it's related to your system's `undo_retention` parameter.

Comment: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, no? What do you mean you can't? Do you get an error? Are there records that appear that you don't expect? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17922106/different-current-timestamp-and-sysdate-in-oracle

Comment: @kchason Hi, i will received empty result, it should not be empty result

Comment: If what you have is truly your WHERE condition, the first part is useless, as for when the second part is true (`COB.COB_FA  > CURRENT TIMESTAMP + 30 days`) the first will inherently always be. Unless that inequality is backwards?

Answer (score 0):

Try below with current_timestamp (+/-) interval '30' day

```
COB.COB_FA  < current_timestamp - interval '30' day or COB.COB_FA  > current_timestamp + interval '30' day
```

Comment: That has the same issue that the initial question has. x > -30 will always be true when x > 30 is true

Comment: @kchason, I thought the only problem is date addition , so I didn't notice it, however thank you for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply want `or`:

```
COB.COB_FA < CURRENT TIMESTAMP - interval '30' day or
COB.COB_FA  > CURRENT TIMESTAMP + '30' day
```

Answer (score 0):

sysdate can do this.

`COB.COB_FA  between sysdate - 30 and sysdate + 30

Answer (score 0):

this will work:

```
create table table_date(dd date);
insert into table_date values(trunc(sysdate));

insert into table_date values(trunc(sysdate)+1);

insert into table_date values(trunc(sysdate)+2);

insert into table_date values(trunc(sysdate)+9);

insert into table_date values(add_months(trunc(sysdate),-5));

//inserting more of them

alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd/MON/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';
SELECT * FROM table_date order by dd;

11/MAY/2018 00:00:00
11/JUL/2018 00:00:00 
11/OCT/2018 00:00:00
12/OCT/2018 00:00:00
13/OCT/2018 00:00:00
18/OCT/2018 00:00:00
20/OCT/2018 00:00:00
11/JAN/2019 00:00:00
11/MAR/2019 00:00:00

SELECT * FROM table_date where dd>add_months(current_timestamp,1) or 
dd<add_months(current_timestamp,-1);
```

sample output:

```
11/JAN/2019 00:00:00
11/MAR/2019 00:00:00
11/JUL/2018 00:00:00
11/MAY/2018 00:00:00
```