# Force Oracle's sysdate to return different value for multiple statements

Tags: oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, sysdate

I'd like to force Oracle `sysdate` function to return different values for separate statements, just like it does in Postgres. I've done some digging over the documentation, net and SO itself but couldn't find an answer to address this.

Documentation seems to be pretty poor for this one: [see for yourself](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions172.htm)

I'm using Oracle 11g with SQL Developer 18.3

Please read on the MVCE below.

After executing this:

```
create table t(a timestamp);
insert into t values (sysdate);
insert into t values (sysdate);
insert into t values (sysdate);
select * from t;
```

I get:

```
A                          
---------------------------
18/12/25 04:25:59,000000000
18/12/25 04:25:59,000000000
18/12/25 04:25:59,000000000
```

I would want to get (changed by hand):

```
A                          
---------------------------
18/12/25 04:25:59,1234
18/12/25 04:25:59,7281
18/12/25 04:26:00,1928
```

Real issue is presented within different `CALL` statements to procedures, but the above sample seems to replicate the issue for me.

---

**UPDATE**

One thing I found to be helpful is to put pauses between statements, but this really isn't what I'm looking for:

```
set pause on;
create table t(a timestamp);
insert into t values (sysdate);
pause
insert into t values (sysdate);
pause
insert into t values (sysdate);
```

Comment: Even if you could do this, are you certain that it would fully resolve your problem?  I mean, suppose that two inserts just happen to occur close enough together that the `SYSDATE` value still appears the same?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not multi-user environment and the purpose is merely for my own training. I'm executing different statements but I do not observe any difference between the calls which is odd for what I've learned from my experience with other DBMSs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that `current_timestamp` does the job:

```
drop table t;
create table t(a timestamp);
insert into t values (current_timestamp);
insert into t values (current_timestamp);
insert into t values (current_timestamp);
select * from t;
```

Outputs:

```
A                          
---------------------------
18/12/25 04:48:54,134000000
18/12/25 04:48:54,142000000
18/12/25 04:48:54,149000000
```

Comment: Since you started with `sysdate`, you might want `systimestamp` rather than `current_timestamp` - [they can give different values](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17925834/266304).

Answer (score 4):

As noted in the documentation, [the `sysdate` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYSDATE.htm) returns a [date](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-5405B652-C30E-4F4F-9D33-9A4CB2110F1B), which only has precision down to seconds - it does not support fractional seconds. So, multiple calls within the same second will always get the same value, and you can't force it to do anything else.

You're putting that date value into a [timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-94A82966-D380-4583-9AF1-AEE681881E64) column, which is causes an implicit conversion from one data type to the other, but that conversion can't set/create a new fractional seconds value - it keeps the implicit fractional seconds from the date, which is of course always zero.

As well as `sysdate`, Oracle has [a `systimestamp` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYSTIMESTAMP.html), which returns a [timestamp with time zone](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-BE23545B-469A-4A57-8D13-505F2F5DB706) value - and that does have fractional seconds. The precision is limited by the platform you're running on. If you use that to populate your plain timestamp column then an implicit conversion still occurs, but you essentially just throw away the time zone information.

Oracle also supports [`current_date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CURRENT_DATE.html) and [`current_timestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.html), which are very similar - except they return the date/time in the current session time zone, rather than in the server time zone as the `sys*` versions do.

Comment: Thanks Alex. It seems to be a matter of choice on where to handle conversions. Good addition :)

Comment: Thanks for explanation, but what if when I have two `sysdate` in a big `select` query that lasts 20 seconds for example. Does Oracle resolves all `sysdate`s or all `systimestamp`s once?

Comment: Looks like these functions are resolved once! `SELECT 'sysdate' AS FUNCTION, sysdate AS RETURN FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'systimestamp', systimestamp FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'systimestamp', systimestamp FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'current_timestamp', current_timestamp FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'systimestamp', systimestamp FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'current_timestamp', current_timestamp FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'sysdate', sysdate FROM DUAL
UNION ALL
SELECT 'systimestamp', systimestamp FROM DUAL` See the values of `RETURN` column for the rows 3, 4, 5, 6 and 8.