# Oracle Database change timezone with OGG Repliction running

Tags: oracle19c, oracle-golden-gate

We have running a oracle database in AWS and getting data from OGG replicated, unfortunately we have not set the correct timezone for the database at first. The database runs now with UTC +-0 but we are in Germany and need UTC +2.

So the query

```
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
```

provide the SYSDATE for UTC +-0

and

```
SELECT CURRENT_DATE FROM DUAL;
```

provides UTC -2

but if i create sheduled jobs or something i must keep that in mind and adjust the time with the 2 hour differences.

We have thought to change the timezone but the fact that we are running OGG Replication and we don't know what will happen or the impact of that keeps us from doing it.

the ogg related columns for replicated tables GG_TRG_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP and GG_SRC_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP have the correct time, not 2hour difference.

Has anyone experience with that? can anyone say that is safe to change the timezone?

That will be really helpful

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/17922106/1509264 for the difference between `SYSDATE` and `CURRENT_DATE`. Are you sure you do not have an XY-problem and are not confusing the session time with the system time?

Comment: sry for the late answer, no i am not confusing anything, GG_TRG_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP has as default value "SYSTIMESTAMP" which is the time 2 hours earlier when i am doing "SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP FROM DUAL" , column GG_TRG_COMMIT_TIMESTAMP has NULL as default value. i am asking if there will be a impact of the replicated data if i change the timezone of the DB that will leading to change SYSTIMESTAMP on our side